# оптимизация скрипта (Fatal error: Allowed memory)

Tags: php, память

Привет! Возникла проблема - при чтении из большой таблицы базы данных скрипт выдаёт ошибку:

> Allow memory...

Код следующий:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table`;');
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $res['id'] . ',';
    unset($res);
}
```

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать, чтобы не получать данную ошибку?

Comment: И снова позанудствую. Расширение mysql ОЧЕНЬ давно объявлено устаревшим, не развивается, а в PHP 7 вообще удалено. Используйте mysqli или PDO.

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно, что большое кол-во данных требует большого кол-ва памяти при работе метода. Для минимального использования памяти на стороне клиентского приложения относительно базы используются курсоры, он у вас используется при помощи функции mysql_fetch_array, которая извлекает следующий результат из курсора.

При использовании функции mysql_query, она буферизирует результат, вы работаете с курсором данных, которые обработаны и сохранены в память скрипта PHP, естественно при большом обьеме данных, обычного размера памяти выделяемого под скрипт не хватит. **Это называется буферизированный запрос.**

На помощь приходит функция mysql_unbuffered_query, она не сохраняет результат выполнения в память, а выполняет перемещение курсора в базе данных, благодаря чему память скрипта не засоряется. **Это называется небуферизированный запрос.**

Тоесть в случае mysql_query вы работате с курсором из памяти PHP, а во втором случае с курсором базы данных. Меняйте **mysql_query** на **mysql_unbuffered_query** и все будет отлично.

Хочу заметить, что **расширение mysql устарело** и его использование небезопасно, как минимум из-за отсутствия функций привязки параметров, и отсуствия поддержки в **PHP 5.5** и выше, воспользуйтесь библиотекой mysqli или PDO, последняя предоставляет более удобный обьектно-ориентированный доступ к данным.

У небуферизированных запросов есть преимущества и недостатки:

**Преимущества:**

1. Результат можно начинать читать раньше, сокращается время ожидания;
2. Результат не занимает место в оперативной памяти.

**Недостатки:**

1. Невозможно узнать, сколько строк получено;
2. Невозможно передвигаться к определенному результату, то есть можно читать данные только с начала и по порядку;
3. Нельзя выполнять других запросов, пока не закрыт этот результат.

Небуферизированный запрос на PDO выглядит вот так:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world", 'my_user', 'my_pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$uresult = $pdo->query("SELECT Name FROM City");
if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
?>
```

На [официальном сайте PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) есть информация по буфферизированным и небуферизированным запросом на английском языке.

**P.S Если вам нужен только ID выбирайте в запросе только id, а не все поля из таблицы**

Comment: Должен признать свою ошибку. Я действительно поменял шило на мыло, по-этому удалил ответ. Вам я плюсик поставлю, ибо узнал о буфферизированных запросах. Спасибо (^_^)

Comment: @CodeStealer Спасибо! :) Ставлю Вам плюс за честность и адекватную реакцию на критику :)

Comment: Как там говорят, век живи, а век учись) Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы оптимизировать работу с памятью при задаче обхода большой таблицы, выбирайте не всю таблицу, а только колонку с первичным ключом из неё:

```
/*Обход большой таблицы с экономией памяти*/
$query = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM `table`;');
while ($id = mysql_fetch_array($query)[0])
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` where id = '.$id.';') );

    /* Делаем что-то с полными данными ряда таблицы $row */
    ...
}
```

Внутри цикла, если того требует задача - выберите полные данные по ряду, зная id. В таком случае каждый шаг цикла, память, захваченная переменной `$row` - отправится в garbage collector, т.е. освободится при необходимости.

Кстати это догма при написании скриптов портирования на PHP. Догма эта правда относится к построителям запросов - которые не различают query и fetch в общем случае для упрощения работы с БД.

Замечу, что драйвер mysql и уязвим, о чём написано на каждой странице php.net, ему посвящённой. Необходимо использовать `PDO` , `Doctrine DBAL` , или на худой конец  `mysqli`.